# How to sort the order of Magento joinLeft

Tags: database, ce-1.7.0.2, collection

I am trying to use a join query in Magento Abandoned Grid this way:

```
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                        'abandoned_comment_history', 'main_table.customer_id=abandoned_comment_history.customer_id', array('admin_comment', 'comment_datetime', 'status'))
                ->group('main_table.customer_id');
```

In my custom table **abandoned_comment_history** there are multiple matches with main **table.customer_id** & i am getting the **first one** but i need **last one**.

Is there any way to get the last match from my custom table. 
I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution. Hope will get here.

Description: In my table **abandoned_comment_history** have some data as

```
id customer_id admin_comment
1     2082      Test 1
2     2082      Test 2
3     2091      Hello
```

In main_table customer_id column is unique.

```
  customer_id 
     2082      
     2084      
     2091
```

Now if i try to **join & get admin_comment** value i get "Test 1" but i need "Test 2"

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query would have to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM main_table c
    LEFT JOIN abandoned_comment_history h ON c.customer_id=h.customer_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT customer_id, MAX(id) FROM abandoned_comment_history GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS m ON h.id = m.id
WHERE 1;
```

I can't give you a solution with the Magento and Zend methods, but I would try to accomplish this query with `$select->join()` and a `Zend_Db_Expr` to use arbitrary SQL expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                        'abandoned_comment_history', 'main_table.customer_id=abandoned_comment_history.customer_id', array('admin_comment', 'comment_datetime', 'status'))
                ->group('main_table.customer_id');

$collection->getSelect()->order('main_table.customer_id ASC');// DESC OR ASC
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                        'abandoned_comment_history', 'main_table.customer_id=abandoned_comment_history.customer_id', array('admin_comment', 'comment_datetime', 'status'))
                ->group('main_table.customer_id');

$collection->setOrder('main_table.customer_id','desc');// desc OR asc
?>
```

Comment: Nopes, I added more details in my question. If some how i can sort by id while joining then i could get the result.